# ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' on python 3.4 win 10

Tags: python, matplotlib

Have installed win 10 on my macbook for working with different plot libraries in python 3.4. I began vs Tkinter, but it is boring, so I followed some forums-speakers and tried matplotlib. I installed it using pip3 and get next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gleb/PycharmProjects/_testing_plot_libraries_/matplotlib_trying.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 30, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyparsing import Literal, ZeroOrMore, \
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 13, in <module>
    from matplotlib import docstring, rcParams
ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams'
```

in simple task:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

what should I do to make it work?
can you give me some advises in plot libraries for science? Im looking for more 2D than 3D plotting libraries.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1280/

Comment: I read it, but im new in python. What kind of name clashing should I avoid? It is my 1 project on this OS.

Comment: I have unistalled pure python and downloaded anaconda. Now everything works