# Scipy won't install properly installation

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, pip

I'm trying to install Scipy through pip, but it won't work. It says that it already is installed, but when I try to import the modules it gives me errors.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TimGF\Documents\Coding\Python\numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from . import cbook
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\TimGF\Documents\Coding\Python\numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 31, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import cbook, docstring, rcParams
ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams'
```

EDIT: It turned out, that the problem was, that I called my file "matplotlib.py".

Comment: You talk about `scipy` but you `import matplotlib`, not clear to me.

Comment: When I try installing manually it with an whl file it gives me this error. "scipy-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: According to your traceback, you have Python 3.6 and you try to install scipy for 2.7, so it might be the problem. or do you have both python version?

Comment: I tried to download it from https://www.scipy.org/install.html
I typed "python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose" but I didn't know it was for 2.7. How do I install it for 3.6?

Comment: try to add a 3 like `python3 -m pip ...`

Comment: Didn't work with the python3 thing. I accidently downloaded it for 2.7, so I tried install the 3.6 file, but it gave an error as well.

"scipy-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: not sure I can help you more, in the comment of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186773/importerror-cannot-import-name-rcparams-on-python-3-4-win-10) the guy says he unsitalled python and isntalled anaconda to make it work. that is one solution

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that I was super stupid, and I just had to rename the python file to something else than "matplotlib.py" since it confused the script.